# Generate commands based on JSON file using the following structure

Tags: python, json, text, command, generate

I am stuck with something and I cannot seem to find a solution to this.

The JSON array below needs to be parsed and all the arguments appended in a command up untill the deepest level.

```
{
  "commands": {
    "dth": {
      "authorization": [],
      "arguments": {
        "user": {
          "description": "This ia the first command description",
          "authorization": [],
          "required": true,
          "hasValue": false,
          "arguments": {
            "create": {
              "required": true,
              "hasValue": false,
              "arguments": {
                "-p": {
                  "required": true,
                  "hasValue": true
                },
                "-u": {
                  "required": true,
                  "hasValue": true,
                  "arguments": {
                    "-n": {
                      "required": true,
                      "hasValue": true
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "update": {
              "required": true,
              "hasValue": false,
              "arguments": {
                "-p": {
                  "required": true,
                  "hasValue": true
                },
                "-u": {
                  "required": true,
                  "hasValue": true,
                  "arguments": {
                    "-n": {
                      "required": true,
                      "hasValue": false
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "delete": {
              "required": true,
              "hasValue": false,
              "arguments": {
                "-u": {
                  "required": true,
                  "hasValue": true
                }
              }
            },
            "search": {
              "required": false,
              "hasValue": true
            }
          }
        },
        "data": {
          "hasValue": true,
          "required": true
        }
      }
    },
    "aloha": {
      "authorization": [],
      "arguments": {
        "save": {
          "required": true,
          "hasValue": true
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The commands generated should look something like this:

/dth user create -n {value} -u {value} -p {value}

I tried this and it did not work, it created duplicates and I am unsure how to properly and efficiently do it.

```
def append_belongs_to_arguments(command, argument_strings, command_details):
    command_list = []
    if 'belongsTo' in command_details:
        for belongs_to in command_details['belongsTo']:
            argument_strings.append(belongs_to)
            nested_command_list = generate_commands(command_details['arguments'], prefix=command,
                                                    parent_key=belongs_to)
            command_list.extend(nested_command_list)
            # Recursive call to handle nested arguments
            append_belongs_to_arguments(command, argument_strings, command_details['arguments'][belongs_to])
    return command_list

def generate_commands(commands, prefix='', command_list=None, parent_key=None):
    if command_list is None:
        command_list = []

    for command, details in commands.items():
        if prefix:
            if parent_key:
                full_command = f"{prefix} {parent_key} {command}"
            else:
                full_command = f"{prefix} {command}"
        else:
            full_command = command

        if 'arguments' in details:
            arguments = details['arguments']
            argument_strings = []
            for argument, argument_details in arguments.items():
                if 'hasValue' in argument_details and argument_details['hasValue']:
                    argument_strings.append(f"{argument} {{value}}")
                else:
                    argument_strings.append(argument)

                if 'arguments' in argument_details:
                    nested_command_list = generate_commands(argument_details['arguments'], prefix=full_command,
                                                            parent_key=argument)
                    command_list.extend(nested_command_list)
                    append_belongs_to_arguments(full_command, argument_strings, argument_details)

            append_belongs_to_arguments(full_command, argument_strings, details)

            if len(argument_strings) == len(arguments):
                command_string = f"{full_command} {' '.join(argument_strings)}"
                command_list.append(command_string)

        if 'hasValue' in details and details['hasValue']:
            full_command = full_command + ' {value}'

        # Add the command if it has arguments or if it's the initial command
        if command_list and (details.get('arguments') or not prefix) and full_command not in command_list:
            command_list.append(full_command)

    return command_list
```

Thanks!